# What should the images look like for a ProgressDrawable layer-list?

Tags: android, image, progress-bar

I am customizing the look of a HORIZONTAL ProgressBar in Android and I have to use three different images, one for the background, one for the secondaryProgress, and one for progress.

My guess would be that the background has to be an actual full bar image for progress to fill in, something like a grey bar image that matches the dimensions of the ProgressBar view layout-width and height?

What about the others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look how the progress_horizontal.xml is defined in the Android core - you can use it as a reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5.0dip" />
            <gradient android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d" android:endColor="#ff747674" android:angle="270.0" android:centerY="0.75" android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5.0dip" />
                <gradient android:startColor="#80ffd300" android:endColor="#a0ffcb00" android:angle="270.0" android:centerY="0.75" android:centerColor="#80ffb600" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5.0dip" />
                <gradient android:startColor="#ffffd300" android:endColor="#ffffcb00" android:angle="270.0" android:centerY="0.75" android:centerColor="#ffffb600" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Perfect. I've visited it before, but have forgotten. Can you tell me how to find the Android source?

Comment: I guess there are multiple ways, finding it on the web (or checking it out from the Android git repo). But what I did is simply unpacking the C:\android-sdk-windows-r04\platforms\android-8\android.jar with apktool (http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)